# Web site with posts talking about humans being overpowered ("OP"), strange, or dangerous from the aliens' perspective

Tags: story-identification, aliens, online-resources

I remember seeing a Web site a couple years ago that explored user-submitted stories where aliens find humans OP, strange, insane, etc., etc. Now I can't find it anywhere.  Does anyone know what I'm referring to? I remember one story being about how humans are just talking meat.

Comment: Can you define "Op"? Is that O.P. as in "overpowered"?

Comment: The "humans are just talking meat" story could very well be "They're Made of Meat" by Terry Bisson.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They%27re_Made_Out_of_Meat

Comment: I dont know the site, but I believe there is a /reddit page? Maybe called Humans are Space Orcs? I listen to a channel on YouTube where a guys reads lots of the stories from pages like you describe. The channel name is "NetNarrator" Here is a link to one of the stories the guy is narrating. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAM6KjIFbmE

Comment: The reddit channel is https://www.reddit.com/r/HFY/ HFY=Humanity F*ck Yeah!

Comment: Thankyou! i think humans are space orks is the one i was on about, been searching for half and hour and you answered in 5 mins so cheers

Comment: Also humanity fuck yeah i was thinking about too, i must of combined them thankyou all

Comment: Yeah I think "Humans are Space Orcs" is just one of the series of stories or a type of the stories, but I just got used to calling it that. But the Site is reddit.com/r/HFY . I never read teh stories there, I just listen to them on YouTube, the NetNarrator does a wonderful job telling them.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the site your looking for is: reddit.com/r/HFY

> We're a writing focused subreddit welcoming all media exhibiting the awesome potential of humanity, known as HFY or "Humanity, Fuck Yeah!" We welcome sci-fi, fantasy, and all other stories with a focus on humans being awesome!

It is a place would be authors post space/alien/Sci-Fi types stories where the humans usually(?) come out on the winning side of alien encounters of all types. (Diplomatic, Military, Trade, etc.)

Many stories are told from the alien point of view, usually indicating that the aliens had no idea the humans were that good/smart/tenacious/etc.

Most of the stories are short, (Though some are posted as a chapter a post, so ARE book length stories when combined) The quality of the short stories is quite good, Up to the quality of professionals in many instances, and very entertaining.

There are several channels on YouTube where the short stories are narrated by the channel creator (most 10-20 minutes long)

One popular one I listen to is NetNarrator. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClXev0oQLuZapY_Jc_kKKTg

I don't browse reddit.com much so there maybe other story posting channels.